# Want to sort a list with two classes using

Tags: java, class

So currently I have two classes, `Human` and `Fysiker`, `Human` taking two arguments, an `age` and a `name`, while `Fysiker` is taking three arguments, `age`, `name` and `startyear`.

Worth noting is that I've extended `Fysiker` with `Human`, my issue is that I want to sort the two of them after ages, which is working perfectly, but if two `Fysiker` got the same age, I want to sort them after `startyear`. Currently I've used `Collections.sort` for this, and it is working to some extent. The problem is that sometimes, let's say I've created 100 objects, 50 `Human` and 50 `Fysiker`, I can get a printout like this:

> Saga, 30 years, 1972 (Fysiker) Tomas, 30 years, 1974 (Fysiker) Nils,
>   30 years (Human) Frida, 30 years, 1969 (Fysiker, sorted wrong, this
>   one should be first)

Notice that this was my printout using `Collections.sort`, is there a way for me to get the printout as it should be, I don't mind a Human being in between but I want all of the `Fysiker` to be sorted in the right way, it almost seems like `Collections.sort` is simply looking at two of them, and sorting those and moving on. My two classes is currently looking like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Human implements Comparable<Human>{
    static Random rand=new Random();
    public int age;
    public String name;
    public static List<String> names=Arrays.asList("hugo","tor","tomas");

    public Human(int age, String name) {
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name; 
    }
    public Human() {
        this.age=rand.nextInt(101);
        this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(3));
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "\n namnet är:"+" "+this.name+" "+"åldern är:"+" "+this.age;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human o) {
        return this.age - o.age;
    }

}
```

And:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Fysiker extends Human {
    int startyear;

    public Fysiker(int age,String name,int startyear) {
        if (startyear>=1932 && startyear<=2015){
            this.startyear=startyear;
            this.age=age;
            this.name=name;}
        else{
            System.out.println("nej");
        }
        if (age>=15 && age<=100){
            this.age=age;
            this.name=name;
            this.startyear=startyear;}
        else{
            System.out.println("nej");}

        }


    public Fysiker() {
        this.startyear = 1932 + rand.nextInt(84);
        this.age = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2015-this.startyear+15, 101);
        this.name = names.get(rand.nextInt(3));
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return String.format("F %02d", this.startyear % 100);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " " + "startåret är:" + " " + String.format("F %02d", this.startyear % 100);
    }

    public int compareTo(Human o) {
        if(this.age==o.age && this instanceof Fysiker && o instanceof Fysiker) {
            return this.startyear-((Fysiker)o).startyear;}

        return super.compareTo(o);}

}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: I was like "Jon Skeet?"

Comment: And just in case you picked your nick name to honor the great Jon Skeet. News for you: your input is not worth using that name. IMHO.

Comment: @GhostCat  I realize that I have plenty to learn and I'm sorry that I brought a sloppy question, I was frustrated that my code didn't work and wanted help. Couldn't help myself looking into your profile finding:
"Besides that: my goal on Stackoverflow is to help other folks solving their problems. " IMHO, I wouldnt flatter myself like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `if` condition from:

```
if(this.age == o.age && this instanceof Fysiker && o instanceof Fysiker)
```

to

```
if(this.age == o.age && o instanceof Fysiker)
```

why is this change necessary?

Assume that two objects have the same age and then you want to check if  `o` is of type `Fysiker`, currently as your code is written it will *always* evaluate to *true* regardless of whether `o` is of type `Fysiker` or not and therefore preventing the evaluation of `o instanceof Fysiker`.

the code within the `if` block should *only* execute if two objects have the same age and `o` is of type `Fysiker` but that's not what your code is doing due to the `&& this instanceof Fysiker`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that help, finally it seems to be working!